# How to access all details of specific promotion

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am looking for Item Collection Or Class Or Method which can provide all details of specific promotion such as Qualifications, Benefits, Private Coupon etc..

[image]

I have tried following syntax but returning null to me

```
var promotionModel = (commerceContext.Objects.OfType<Promotion>()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by using the IFindEntityPipeline, you can see a dummy implementation on how to achieve that here:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IFindEntityPipeline _findEntityPipeline;

    public Foo(IFindEntityPipeline findEntityPipeline)
    {
        _findEntityPipeline = findEntityPipeline;
    }

    public async Task<Promotion> GetPromotionById(string id, CommercePipelineExecutionContext context)
    {
        var promotion = await _findEntityPipeline.Run(new FindEntityArgument(typeof(Promotion), id, 1), context))
        return promotion as Promotion;
    }
}
```